# Sobre o TADEventAlert da suite de componentes FireDAC. O que é e para que serve?

Tags: delphi, delphi-xe3, delphi-xe4, firedac

Continuando a querer saber sobre componentes do `FireDAC`, suite de componentes adquirida pela **Embarcadero** para o `Delphi`, gostaria de saber sobre o componente `TADEventAlert`.

**Para que serve esse componente, qual a finalidade e por favor, pode dar um exemplo?**

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Este componente é utilizado para receber notificações disparadas pelo SGDB. Estas notificações devem ser implementadas pelo desenvolvedor através de triggers ou stored procedures no banco.

Você pode notificar o sistema toda vez que uma tabela for alterada, ou alertando que determinada operação será executada (como um backup ou fechamento de caixa).

Para um detalhamento maior, pode conferir a página de documentação do componente na wiki da embarcadero neste **[link](http://docwiki.embarcadero.com/RADStudio/XE6/en/Database_Alerts_%28FireDAC%29)**